# SQL Join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables :TAB1 and TAB2.

TAB1 fields : itemid(p) and description
TAB2 fields : itemid(F) and parentitems.

TAB2 is subitems of TAB1 so I want to retrieve the all items from TAB1 and parent items equivalent item desciption from TAB1.

Please find the below Query.

```
Select 
    t1.itemid ,
    t1.DESC, 
    t2.parentitems,
    t2.DESC 
from TAB1 t1 left join TAB2 t2 on t1.itemid = t2.parentitems 
where 
    some conditions...
```

Let me give some sample values..

TAB1:

```
item   Desc
A1     aa
A2     bb
A3     cc
A4     dd
```

TAB2:

```
item   parentitems
A1     A1
A1     A2
A4     A2
A4     A2
```

How to retrieve parent items equivalent desc from TAB1 ?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but it sounds like something like this:

```
Select 
    t1.item item,
    t1.Desc desc1, 
    t2.parentitems pitem
    ,t1_2.Desc desc2
from TAB1 t1 left join TAB2 t2 on t1.item = t2.item
left join TAB1 t1_2 on t2.parentitems = t1_2.item
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be4db/12)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use recursives. for more info see [here](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2009/11/recursive-subquery-factoring.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below is MS SQL Server base query statement.

SELECT        TAB2.parentitems, TAB2.itemid, TAB1.description
FROM            TAB1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         TAB2 ON TAB1.itemid = TAB2.parentitems

---

Good Luck... :)

Chamath Jeevan